# Estimate Delivery Date on product grid and product page - magento

Tags: magento, date

I am trying to show `Estimate Delivery Date` on every product page and also as a label on category page. For reference i want the same functionality as on this website [indiabazaaronline](http://www.indiabazaaronline.com) .

If you hover on the aeroplane label, it will show `estimated delivery date`, also on product page and also it varies for different products.

For international customers i want to set a date `T+20` days for delivery. For local(India)
`T+6` days. The dates should automatically change if I open the page next day.

For example if its showing estimated delivery date as `21st September,2014`, the next day it should say estimated delivery date is `22nd September,2014`

I am using Magento 1.9

Tried two extensions **Product Delivery Date** & **Order Delivery Date** but didn't solve the purpose as I don't want my customer to select the date.

Found this - [Estimate Delivery Date on Stackoverflow](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/14371/magento-expected-delivery-date-on-product-page)
But I am not able get it to work as I am not a magento developer but I can code in PHP.
The website I want to implement this functionality is [indiacraftonline](http://indiacraftonline.com)

Please help!!!

Comment: You need this label in product list,product detailed page and entire check out pages. Right?

Answer (score 1):

You can try using `Custom option`, in admin panel, open the product, last option on left side is CUSTOM OPTION. over their use date and time or just date as per your wish and that's it.

Specify custom product options on-the-fly on quote items `(Ex:adding Delivery date with each product in the orders)` You can make use of an observer to add a `custom option`

To achieve you can try below code

```
<controller_action_predispatch_checkout>
<observers>
<options_observer>
<class>YOUR_CLASS_NAME</class>
<method>setProductInfo</method>
</options_observer>
</observers>
</controller_action_predispatch_checkout>

$deliveryDate = $prId['delivery_date'];
if (!empty($deliveryDate)) {
$opt['options'] = array($optionID => $deliveryDate);
$request->setParams($opt);
}
return $this;
```

Another method is to create one input text and create and observer for when product is added to cart. Over there if you will check the posted data you will find the value for your input text.

Comment: If I add an attribute of type date and set that attribute to all the attribute sets with a default value of T+20 days. Then how will the value will change. Also it will remain same for each and every product unless I use diffrent attribute everytime.

Comment: If you have two different groups for international customers and local customers, you have to mention the date only after they login. Else you can specify it based on GeoIP i.e. location of customer. If international then `T+20` else `T+6`.